# Using accented symbols on VIM

Tags: linux, vim

Few hours ago I changed from my old Debian box to a new one, when I did that I bring with me the .vimrc I use on the old unit.

On the old one I can use : áéóçãñ, etc normally (first the simbol ' then the letter)

On my new machine I simply can't do this, I always get A followed by some obscure symbol.

I already checked my encoding and it is utf-8 on both machines.

Also in both machines I can use accents on bash prompt, so the problem is with vim.

Does someone have a tip to fix that?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:
I just found a difference, on my old machine I have VIM 7.3 on the new one it is 7.2.445, could be this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. I don't know why, but as I said encoding utf-8 don't work for me then I started trying others and I found that encoding iso-8859 solved my problem on that machine. weird that on my old machine its works over utf-8.

Comment: I presume you're running vim in a terminal window... what's the encoding in use in the terminal?

Comment: I'm using the same Putty on Windows 7 to access two distinct Debian servers, since it used to work for one but not to other I don't think this was the problem. But i've made a question I don't know how to answer... which encoding putty uses?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
set encoding=utf-8
```

in your `vimrc`

Comment: I already did this, and checked with ":set encoding?" and the encoding is already setted to utf-8. But still not working well.